# How to render a tricky ass NinePatch?

Tags: android

This is thebasic idea, but the image is ugly and pixelated. WHY???

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_default_normal);
    NinePatchDrawable npd = new NinePatchDrawable(bmap, bmap.getNinePatchChunk(), new Rect(0,0,512,512), "name");
    npd.mutate();
    npd.setBounds(new Rect(0,0,512,512));
    npd.invalidateSelf();
    Bitmap bp = Bitmap.createBitmap(512,512, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bp);
    npd.draw(canvas);
    FileOutputStream ofo=null;
    try {
      ofo = openFileOutput("image", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ofo);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getFileStreamPath("image").toURI());
    intent.setType("image/png");
    //startActivity(intent);
    iv.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bp));
  }
}
```

Comment: I originally downrated this question, but I've changed my mind.  This adds flavor.

Comment: Why don't you post the actual "tricky ass" NinePatch and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: All of the information is there. The nine patch is btn_default_normal.9.png easily obtainable from android's open source

Comment: And what is it that you are trying to accomplish? Your "basic idea" looks like anything but.

Comment: Take a 9 patch image, and stretch it to 512px. the above code stretches, but the result looks horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it infinitely more complicated than it needs to be. Just set your view in the XML like so:

```
<TextView
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default_small"        
        android:layout_width="512px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NinePatch View"
        />
```

Just using TextView as an example. The same will work for an ImageView, a View, pretty much any widget. The important thing to remember is to use the `background` attribute instead of the `src` attribute for an ImageView. The `src` attribute will stretch the image as is, it won't respect the NinePatch data.

If you're set on doing it in code, just use:

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_small)
```

As a side note, what device are you displaying it on? Most mobile phones only have up to 480 pixels for the width.

Comment: I was hoping to make an app out of this....now I'm forced to reveal my hand. Oh well....progress is more important ;)